# Erros while trying to make factroy method with c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, methods, factory

I am trying to use this example code:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/1
in order to make it work for me for a program I try to improve.
Here is my code according the files:
VCFReader.h

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream> // files
#include <locale> // unicode chars and strings
#include <cstdlib> // for exit()
#include <vector> // vector of VCFRecords
#include "VCFRecord.h"
#include "VCFReader3_0.h"
#include "VCFReader2_1.h"

class VCFReader 
{
public:
    static VCFReader *makeVCFReader(std::wstring version); // factory method
    virtual vector<VCFRecord> loadVCFRecordsFromFile(std::wstring pathToFile) = 0;
};
```

VCFReader.cpp:

```
#include "VCFReader.h"

VCFReader *VCFReader::makeVCFReader(std::wstring version)
{
    if (version == L"VERSION:3.0")
    {
        return new VCFReader3_0;
    }
    else if (version == L"VERSION:2.1")
    {
        return new VCFReader2_1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string throwMessage = "Unsupported version: " + std::string(version.begin(), version.end());
        throw throwMessage.c_str();
    }
}
```

VCFReader3_0.h (the same as VCFReader2_1.h):

```
#pragma once

#include "VCFReader.h"

class VCFReader3_0 : public VCFReader
{
    virtual vector<VCFRecord> loadVCFRecordsFromFile(std::wstring pathToFile);
};
```

But I get these errors:

> Error C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'VCFReader2_1 *' to
> 'VCFReader *' vcfreader.cpp   11
>
> Error C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'VCFReader3_0 *' to
> 'VCFReader *' vcfreader.cpp   7

and multiple times

> Error C2504   'VCFReader': base class undefined  vcfreader2_1.h   5
>
> Error C2504   'VCFReader': base class undefined  vcfreader3_0.h   5

As I did a little search I found that the error c2504 is caused by circular definitions. But I cannot think of a way to not include the base class in the derived ones as they derive from it and at the same time if I don't include the derived classes in the base class then I cannot return new derived classes in the static function.
Also - why I get this error - C2440 and how to clear it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that the specific-version reader classes are being defined before `VCFReader` in at least one compilation unit, and you can't inherit from an undefined/incomplete type.  The compiler *must* see the definition of `VCFReader` before any classes that inherit from it.  (This is the source of the "base class undefined" error.)

The definition of `VCFReader` does not depend on the definition of the specific version implementations, so the circular includes aren't even necessary.  To solve the circular issue you can either remove these two lines:

```
#include "VCFReader3_0.h"
#include "VCFReader2_1.h"
```

Or, move them *after* the definition of the `VCFReader` class.  (If you remove them, you will have to include them in `VCFReader.cpp`.)

The conversion errors (`cannot convert from 'VCFReader2_1 *' to 'VCFReader *'`) are a side-effect of the "base class undefined" errors -- since the compiler didn't know what `VCFReader` was when the reader version classes were encountered, it doesn't think they inherit from `VCFReader` and so it doesn't think you should be able to upcast the pointers.  Solving the "base class undefined" error should also resolve these conversion errors.

Comment: After moving these includes in the cpp file everything works fine. Thanks! That solved the errors.